# First arrival timings

Tags: probability

Customers depart from a bookstore according to a Poisson process with rate  per hour. Each customer
buys a book with probability p, independent of everything else.

(a) Find the distribution of the time until the rst sale of a book.
(b) Find the probability that there are no books sold during a particular hour.
(c) Find the expected number of customers who buy a book during a particular hour.

i am solving for a

$(p/\lambda) * (1-p/\lambda)^n$.

However, in this case how would i be able to know the n? I know that they are independent so is the distribution of the first arrival independent of n?

Thanks.

Comment: That looks as if it might be a geometric distribution where $n$ is the random variable, though you will need $p \le lambda$.  It is not at all clear what led to that expression

Comment: @Henry This is my solution. So was wondering if its correct

Comment: So customers leave the bookstore at a rate of $\lambda$, and $p$ of them have a book they want to buy on their way out. Then the rate of arrival at the counter is $p\lambda$. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @Arthur I have posted the question in its entirety